# Finding View in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm having a little truble finding a TableLayout in my fragmet.

For context: I want to generate a table with some TextViews in it.

The Code is running but i can't see the Table. While debugging i found, that i havent found the TableLayout. (the debugg said: tl = null).

I've tried instead of getActivity getView, but got an nullPointerExteption. It seems have no acess to the Layout.

After a little more research, i think the error is coming from the onCreate function.

My code

````
 @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
       genTabelle();
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stundenplan, container, false);

       return view;
   }
   public stundenplanFragment(){
     //empty constructor
   }

   //generating the Table
   public void genTabelle(){
       for(int i=1; i<12; i++){
           //finding the Table
           TableLayout tl = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tableLayout2);

   }
}
```code``
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment does not know about the inflated ViewGroup object (hierarcy) in the onCreateView() method, thats why you have to return the mentioned ViewGroup instance.

Just call the *genTabelle()* method in the fragment's *onViewCreated()* lifecycle method. In this lifecycle method the fragment already have a reference for its layout.

Comment: the getActivity() is still necessary. But it works now thanks

Comment: Because you attached the fragment's layout to container. Even so I have updated my answer to your use case, happy coding!